# Converting a vector of strings into an enum class with variables with the same name as strings

Tags: c++

I would like to convert a vector of strings, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::string> fruit = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
```

into an enum class, as follows:

```
enum class fruitID : uint32_t {
 Apple = 0;
 Banana = 1;
 Orange = 2;

 _size
};
```

I'd appreciate any pointers to solve this, as I couldn't really find a good way of doing this looking through different answers. Thanks!

Comment: This is a code generation problem, and C++ doesn't really do that natively.

Comment: An enum is something you create in source code and it get compiled into the program.  You can't create an enum at runtime.

Comment: You can't really do that. If you need to create association between strings and integers at runtime you could always use std::map

Comment: there is unfortunately a huge gap betwen what we all would like enums to be and what they actually are. Its not too wrong to think of them as a bunch of constants, with names just like other variables in your code have a name

Comment: Enums are compile time constants. You cannot add or delete elements from enums at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments already there is **no way to do this in C++ natively**. You would have to generate source files dynamically in order to solve your problem.

The closest you can probably get is using a map as proxy. You can dynamically create it from your vector of strings and it is easy to use within the code, however, no compile-time checking for any range of valid values.

```
std::vector<std::string> fruit = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};

int i = 0;
std::map<std::string, int> fruitID;
for (const auto& f : fruit)
{
    fruitID[f] = i++;
}
```

Then use `fruitID["Apple"]` etc. to use your "dynamic enum" in the code.